# Layout break with recursive components in VueJS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm having trouble solving a problem.
I need to load some components dynamically.
And when loading some of these components, they are presented
faulty or no css styles, and all because of that first div element after the template.
When editing the DOM, and removing this DIV everything was correct.
However, VueJS does not let you use v-for in root.

I am using Vuetify components, so in some cases the Vuetify css needs a level that meets your css class, so this DIV cannot be between a component.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

ControlsComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(component, index) in childs" :key="index" draggable>      
      <component :is="component.Type">
        <ControlsComponent :parent="component" :childs="component.Childs"></ControlsComponent>
      </component>      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What do you mean by faulty? Can you show the code where this component (containing the for loop) is rendered?  My guess is you just need to add a class or ID there.

Comment: The problem was that the loop was being made on the children, I had to make the change and include a structure for the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this component have a parent? If it has try to put it into for-loop in parent. If it doesnt have a parent create one and make the for loop there. For example:
Parent Component:

```
<Child v-for="(component, index) in childs" :key="index" draggable></Child>
```

Child Component

```
<component :is="component.Type">
 <ControlsComponent :parent="component" :childs="component.Childs"></ControlsComponent>
</component>
```